# Safari does not include margins to the scroll width

Tags: css, safari

I have a container that scrolls horizontally, inside that container, I have a bunch of items, on the last item I add a margin to the right. In All browsers except safari, that margin is added to the scroll width.

To reproduce it just run the sample in safari and chrome and scroll to the right end.

Any idea how to force safari to add that margin to the scroll width using only CSS/SCSS?

```css
.scroll {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  background: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.item:last-of-type {
  margin-inline-end: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that works for me. Instead of `margin-inline-end`, I decided to use `::after` element, which is going to act as that margin, this works also for RTL.

```css
.scroll {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: red;
}
.scroll::after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  min-width: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div dir="rtl" class="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
  </div>
</div>
```